# Is it legal to distribute a closed source X Window Manager?

Tags: open-source, linux

I’m doing a thought experiment about making a product on top of Linux. I’m wondering: If you make a custom window manager (akin to KDE, for example) on top of X and you release it, do you have to release it under the GPL (Linux) or MIT (X.org)? Or can you keep it closed source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X-Windows is licensed under the MIT License, which is a permissive license.  Its only requirement appears to be that you include a copy of the MIT license, and do not restrict others from using the X-Windows software in any way they see fit.

The MIT License doesn't require you to make your own software open-source, nor does it prevent you from closing the X-Windows source in the context of your Window manager.

Comment: Another thing I’m wondering: When you make a WM “on top of X”, I’m guessing you’re linking to Xlib, which means you’re not really modifying X itself, but you’d still need to ship with it, correct?

Comment: The MIT License doesn't specify any "bundling" requirements.  I'm guessing the obvious answer to your question is "yes," since your windowing software won't work without it.  Some software leans on dependency mechanisms like `yast` to get the necessary prerequisites.

Comment: You would not need to ship with it, if you only released your software for systems that already had Xlib.